# Background Service Getting My Phone Heated Up

Tags: android, service, locationlistener, background-service

I have a code which runs a service that get's user location update, the service is running fine.. however my phone is heating up for just after minutes of the service running.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    TrackLocation tl = new TrackLocation(); 
    if(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "service started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600000, 150, tl);
    }else{
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 600000, 150, tl);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

that is how I start the service, I don't know what's wrong I'm newbie at android dev. Please help! :(

Comment: Your phone heating up means you're using more power.  Things that use more power would be the processor staying on, transfering a lot of data (transmission takes power), GPS use, etc.  GPS shouldn't heat it up too quickly though.  I don't see anything scary in the code you posted, although its possible TrackLocation is just killing the CPU.  

Does the device make this much heat when you use Google Maps?

Comment: I can't remember, but I know my phone heats up when I use Google Map, might it be because GPS and Mobile Data is turned on at the same time? Because my app need those to work properly.

Comment: If your phone also heats up when it uses Google maps, then I'd assume this is an issue with your GPS chipset just using a lot of power.  In that case its unavoidable.  Yes, using both things at once does use more power, but honestly just about anything that uses GPS also uses internet-  Google maps especially (it has to download maps, directions, etc).